# How to get more than 1024 characters in a GROUP_CONCAT with AWS RDS

Tags: mysql, amazon-web-services, amazon-rds, group-concat

I cant get more than 1024 characters in a GROUP_CONCAT statement. I changed the value of group_concat_max_len to 2048 in AWS RDS Aurora MySQL as shown below

[image]

Then i changed the parameter group of my DB cluster to "new"

[image]

After this I applied the change immediatly to my DB cluster and even with that it doesnt work, all my SELECT queries with a GROUP_CONCAT only return me 1024 characters. What could I be doing wrong?

PD: My DB cluster is a serverless Aurora MySQL on us-west-2 region

Comment: Have you found any solution?

Comment: No. The answer is that is not possilbe. I had to change all my logic in my queries

Comment: It's a pity! I, too, when raising the DB class, every time I change this parameter `auroraDB.executeStatement({...params, sql: 'SET SESSION group_concat_max_len = 1000000;'}).promise()`