# How to change group_concat_max_len on AWS RDS

Tags: mysql, amazon-web-services, amazon-rds, group-concat

I have a DB cluster with AWS RDS MySQL serverless. I changed the parameter group group_concat_max_len to 4096, but when run this query: SHOW VARIABLES LIKE '%group_concat%' it gives me 1024 (which is the default value). How can i change it?

Comment: Isn't this essentially the same as your previous question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63731995/how-to-get-more-than-1024-characters-in-a-group-concat-with-aws-rds

Comment: not an answer to your question, but consider using mariadb 10.2 or above instead of mysql?  it defaults to 1048576 there

Answer (score 3):

For Aurora MySQL Serverless cluster, modifications to only few parameters will take effect. For all other configuration parameters, cluster will use default values even when you modify it. 'group_concat_max_len' is not in the list, so even if you make changes to its value, it will not take effect.

From AWS doc:
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/AuroraUserGuide/aurora-serverless.how-it-works.html

Comment: Sadly this is true